# Being unable to send request using different proxies in Python (using requests module)

Tags: python, http, proxy, python-requests

I am trying to send a request to a URL with a proxy using *requests* module of *Python (3.6.5)*. The request has been done successfully, but when I check the origin of the request (by printing `req.content`), it still shows my IP. Checking through the examples over the Internet, I couldn't get the point behind this problem.

```
def send_request(url):

    header = get_random('UserAgents.txt')
    proxy = get_random('ProxyList.txt')

    print("Proxy: " + str(proxy))

    proxies = {
       'http' : 'http://' + str(proxy),
    }

    try:
        session = requests.Session()
        session.proxies = proxies
        session.headers = HEADER

        req = session.get(url)
        # req = requests.get(url, headers = { 'User-Agent' : HEADER 
        # }, proxies = proxies)

        print(req.content)

        req.raise_for_status()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        sys.exit()

    print('Request is successful!')
    return req
```

Comment: Can you give the url so we can try it? Also the part you commented out, have you tried it?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, You can try it with the following URL: 'https://httpbin.org/ip' (I am also trying with this for now). Yes, I have tried the commented out section too, but it returns the same result.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that your particular proxy may not hide your i.p. You can try one of these free proxies (results are in json format)

[getproxylist](https://gimmeproxy.com/api/getProxy?supportsHttps=true&protocol=http&ipPort=false)

[gimmeproxy](https://gimmeproxy.com/api/getProxy?supportsHttps=true&protocol=http&ipPort=false)

[pubproxy](http://pubproxy.com/api/proxy?https=true&type=http&speed=3)

and see if that works. btw, if what you want is anonymous web access, vpn is far better than proxy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried the proxies from your recommended sites, but I got the same results again. However, when I changed the type of proxy from 'http' to 'https' (which was returning an error about being not valid proxy), it also successfully changed the origin.